# How to share code auto-fill suggestions from a seperate instance of vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, filesystems, autofill, project-structure

I'm working on a project which relies on a library, they both were in the same folder before but out of curiosity I split them into seperate folders, i.e 'Github' containing 'Caldro' folder and 'Volley_Valley' folder seperately

```
-Github
  -Caldro
  -Volley_Valley
```

Now I use 2 different instances of vs code to open each repo seperately, after a few mins of resolving file links everything is peachy, till to my horror, I realize that code suggestions and auto-fill for Caldro are gone!

Is there a way to link of both open instances of vs code to allow them share code suggestions? One-way sharing is alright as well

The only solution I could find is to revert to the old structure, i.e 'Github' containing 'Volley_Valley' folder, which contains 'Caldro'

```
-Github
  -Volley_Valley
    -Caldro
```

But I don't want Caldro to be inside the Volley_Valley Folder, and I can't quite open the "Github" folder in Vs code without messing up Live Server, what do ( do? T_T